# Segmented Control with icon programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on my second Task with swift with MVVM architecture and without storyboard so I tried to code my Segmented Control programmatically with items of type [String] and it works great but now I want to change items with icon/image.

I tried to change type of items from [String] to [UIImage]...

```
import UIKit

class VehicleSegmentedControl:UIControl {
    private var labels = [UILabel]()
    var thumbView = UIView()

    // here are my items of icons
    var items:[UIImage?] = [UIImage(named: "car.png"),UIImage(named: "feet.png"),UIImage(named: "transit.png")]{
        didSet{
            setupLabels()
        }
    }

    var selectedIndex : Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            displayNewSelectedIndex()
        }
    }

    init(items: [UIImage]) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.items = items
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.walkthroughOrangeAccent.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        setupLabels()
        insertSubview(thumbView, at: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var selectedFrame = self.bounds
        let newWith = selectedFrame.width / CGFloat(items.count)
        selectedFrame.size.width = newWith
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        thumbView.frame = selectedFrame
        thumbView.backgroundColor = .walkthroughOrangeAccent
        thumbView.layer.cornerRadius = thumbView.frame.height / 2

        let labelHeight = self.bounds.height
        let labelWidth = self.bounds.width / CGFloat(labels.count)

        for index in 0...labels.count - 1 {
            let label = labels[index]
            let xPosition = CGFloat(index) * labelWidth
            label.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition,y: 0,width: labelWidth,height: labelHeight)
        }
    }

    override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        var calculatedIndex: Int?
        for(index, item) in labels.enumerated()  {
            if item.frame.contains(location){
                calculatedIndex = index
            }
        }
        if calculatedIndex != nil {
            selectedIndex = calculatedIndex!
            sendActions(for:.valueChanged)
        }
        return false
    }

    func displayNewSelectedIndex(){
        let label = labels[selectedIndex]
        self.thumbView.frame = label.frame
    }

    func setupLabels(){
        for label in labels {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        labels.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        for index in 0..<items.count{
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
            //label.text = items[index - 1]
            //label.textAlignment = .center
            //label.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

            //here is my ImageView
            let imgview = UIImageView(image: items[index])

            self.addSubview(imgview)
            labels.append(label)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting 3 icons displayed on each other and not aligned.

Comment: Your `layoutSubviews` does nothing with the image views. It still updates the labels.

Comment: Thank you very much but  can you please explain in more detail how to do that I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: You already know what to do. Just set the frames of the image views instead of the labels.